# How to Pass Data Value to where condition in Snow Flake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement in which I need pass Current Date value to the where condition of a select statement.

Below is the code:

```
var step01 = `SELECT  CURRENT_DATE::DATE`;
var statement01 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: step01} );
results1 = statement01.execute();
results1.next();
Var1 = results1.getColumnValue(1);
Var2 =`Insert into TableA ( ColA) select ColB from tableB
     where  cast(LOAD_DTTM as date) >= TO_DATE(''''${Var1}'''')`;
```

I am getting the following error. Could you please help.

```
Failed: Code: 100183
State: P0000
Message: Date 'Fri Mar 04 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)' is not recognized
Stack Trace: undefined
```

Please advise

Comment: In step01, try casting the date to a string in a format that works if you use it when running the INSERT statement through the UI e.g. something like 'yyyy-mm-dd'